# Meaning of python indexing. e.g. t[...,0]

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

```
tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
        lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t[...,0],
                             scale=1))
```

I am trying to use tensorflow probability, but I am not sure about the indexing`t[...,0]` used in `tfd.Normal` function.

What does it mean? Is `...` equal to `:`?